# Change the header for the printed web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, ajax

How I can change the header of this page.

[image]

and what I need is to create a custom header over red line.

I'm using this script to print the page without opening it:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function closePrint () {   
document.body.removeChild(this.__container__); } 
function setPrint () {  
this.contentWindow.__container__ = this;   
this.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = closePrint;   
this.contentWindow.onafterprint = closePrint;   
this.contentWindow.focus(); 
this.contentWindow.print(); }

function printPage (sURL) {   
var oHiddFrame = document.createElement("iframe");   
oHiddFrame.onload = setPrint;   
oHiddFrame.style.visibility = "hidden";   
oHiddFrame.style.position = "fixed";   
oHiddFrame.style.right = "0";   
oHiddFrame.style.bottom = "0";   
oHiddFrame.src = sURL;   
document.body.appendChild(oHiddFrame); }
        </script>
```

Comment: This print dialog box is system dialog box and probably we can't change its title

Comment: Add Title to the webpage. Then that title will reflect over there.

Comment: Or look into adding a print-only stylesheet.

Comment: thank u, that work for me, but what about the footer, can I change it